# c++ auto_pointer not access class member function

Tags: c++, c++11

Here I want to access class member function using auto pointer. Initially I typedef auto pointer and then allocation memory using new. after that I try to access member function of class A. I gives me below error. expected unqualified-id before ‘->’ token
 pt_a->a_fun();

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
    void a_fun() {
        cout<<"CLASS-A"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    typedef auto_ptr<A> pt_a;
    Auto pointer pointing to class A
    pt_a(new A); 
    pt_a->a_fun();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pt_a` is a *type*, not an *object*. How does `pt_a->a_fun();` even make sense? It is like writing `A->a_fun()` where `A` is the class you defined.

Comment: Accept A.a_fun() will work. Because it is Object.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of points:

1. You tagged C++11, so don't use `std::auto_ptr`. It was deprecated in 2011, and flat out removed in 2017.
2. `typedef ... pt_a;` makes `pt_a` name a type. As such `pt_a->a_fun()` would be ill-formed. You can't use member access on a type, you need an object.
3. `pt_a(new A);` does create an object. A temporary object. It's cleaned up immediately. You don't have any named objects in your program.

So taking all of the above to heart:

```
using pt_a_t = std::unique_ptr<A>; // Same as a typedef, but IMO more readable
pt_a_t pt_a{ new A }; // Declare an object named pt_a
pt_a->a_fun(); // Member access
```